# Attach event handlers for click event on all elements in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, events, jquery-events

I want to be able to figure out which part of my page has been clicked. There is no guarantee the elements are all on the page from the get go, which means that I need to use something like jQuery delegate.

One way to do this is to iterate through all elements in the DOM and then attach an event handler to each element - but this will be slow and complicated - every time new html is dynamically added, I'd have to either re-attach all the handlers, or figure out the subset of html that was added.

The other way is to use event bubbling - so add an event handler to the document, or body and rely upon the events bubbling up.

Something like this:

```
$('body').delegate('div', 'click', function(e){
    dummyId++;
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
    console.log("=====");

});
```

However, after using this code, when I click on buttons on my page, I get the div surrounding the button, as opposed to the actual button. In other words, the above is too specific. Furthermore, I feel like the original selector should be the document, rather than the body tag.

To be clear, I want to know when any element is clicked on my page - how do I do that?

So I tried this code with `.on`:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e){
    console.log("EVENT DUMMY ID");

    console.log(e.target);
    console.log("=====");

});
```

However, when I click on buttons in my app, nothing gets triggered - when I click on other elements, the console logs run.

I understand this is probably hard to answer without more context - what else do you need?

Comment: Don't use selector-based delegation. Just bind a handler to the `document`, and check the `e.target`. That'll be the most deeply clicked element. `$(document).on("click", function(e) { console.log(e.target.nodeName); })`

Comment: on cannot work - I dynamically append html elements

Comment: Before you say it can't work, try it. There's no reason it won't work for dynamically created elements, assuming I've understood you correctly that you want the most deeply clicked element.

Comment: I have tried it - https://api.jquery.com/on/ - also backs me up - "Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on()."

Comment: cookie monster's code will work, precisely because he's binding to the document - an element that is present from the start - and only when in the callback interrogating the actual element that invoked the event, be it one that was there from the start or added later.

Comment: @praks5432: You're either misunderstanding the documentation or how handlers are bound. The event handler is bound to the `document`, which always exists on the page. If you tried it and it didn't work as you claim, you did something wrong.

Comment: OK - so I updated the question with what I tried - it's not working - can you see a mistake/what other context do you need?

Comment: The only thing that'll prevent it from working would be if your button or an ancestor of your button did `e.stopPropagation()` or `return false`. This would keep the event from bubbling up to the `document`, disabling your attempt at delegation.

Comment: so I've noticed that all of the elements on which nothing is triggered are <a> - is there something special about links?

Comment: You mean other than the fact that a link with an `href` pointing to a page will load the page?

Comment: yes - something that interferes with the emitting of a click event?

Comment: Well, if you redirect to different page, or reload the current page, I'd imagine that would interfere with the handler.

Comment: Re "...which means that I need to use something like jQuery ", I think jQuery is written in javascript, and does nothing you cannot do yourself (maybe after a whole lot of head-scratching).  The idea of jQuery is (a) to make it easier (as opposed to possible) and (b) deal with cross-browser incompatibilities, so you don't have to.

Answer (score 15):

`currentTarget` returns the node to which the event has bubbled (if at all). Instead, interrogate `target`, so:

**Vanilla:**

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    alert(evt.target.tagName);
}, false);
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).on('click', function(evt) {
    alert(evt.target.tagName);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qsbdr/

Comment: This fiddle shows that the addEventListener handles dynamically added elements.  http://jsfiddle.net/qsbdr/2/

Answer (score 0):

Just Do this:

```
var listener = function handleClick(event){
    element = event.target
    console.log(element) 
    }

var body = document.body
body.addEventListener('click', listener, true);
```

This will print the element clicked on the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same type of problem to find out which element is clicked on the navbar. I was working in animation slide. So, To solve it, I try to handling all the events of `<ul>`

**TO BE NOTED:** This is just for a piece of block. Not entire webpage.

Here is my reactjs code. Concept is same.

**jsx**

```
        <ul className="right" onClick={setRainbow}>
            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink to="/contact">Contact</NavLink></li>
        </ul>
```

**function**

```
    const setRainbow = (e) => {
            console.log(e.target)
            console.log(e.target.href)
            console.log(e.target.text)
        if (e.target.text === 'About') {
            // to do
        } else {
            // to do
        }
    }
```

- 

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
   // now use e.target here
});
```

You can also kill the bubbling on the click event by using `e.stopPropagation()`

Comment: Also, you don't need `e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement` in jQuery. It does that for you. And `.live()` has been removed from jQuery.

Comment: if he uses old jquery `live()` is there... `on()` has been added since version 1.7

Comment: True, but the way `.live()` works, it relies on a selector being passed. Doing `$(document).live(` won't work because it provides no selector to use for delegation. Change `.live()` to `.bind()` to accommodate old versions of jQuery, and it'll work.

Comment: yep, never mind.. looks like he is using newer version of the jQuery

Comment: NOTE that for the click event to work on other buttons on the page, those buttons should NOT have `e.stopPropagation();` in their click function... Otherwise this click event on document won't be fired when you click on such buttons on the page... I just thought to mention this if someone is having such problem...

Answer (score -1):

I don't see any need to use jQuery for something like this, though my suggestion does rely on MutationEvents, which I understand are to be replaced.

You can get notified upon the insertion of any new node into the DOM. In the callback that fires, you can trivially attach an onclick handler to the new node. I've only handled the case where new nodes are added.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded()
{
    window.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', onNodeInserted, false);
    document.body.appendChild( newEl('div') );
}

function onNodeInserted(evt)
{
    evt.srcElement.addEventListener('click', onNodeClicked, false);
}

function onNodeClicked()
{
    document.body.appendChild( newEl('div') );
}
</script>
<style>
div
{
    border: solid 1px red;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about browser support?

Comment: IE9, Opera 12.15, Chrome 33.0.1750.154 m, default browser on Android 2.3. All tested and functional.